# PHP add JavaScript function return data to database

Tags: javascript, php, sql, jsonp

I want the variable $con to get data(country) from a JavaScript function and save it in SQL database. the insert query is working fine without JavaScript code but when I want to add $con into my database using insert query, the insert query do not add data to my SQL database

Here is my code:

```
$con = "<script>
        function jsonpCallback(data) {
            var con = document.write(data.address.country) }
        </script>
        <script src='http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=jsonpCallback'></script>";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `searched1`
                (`search`, `longitude`, `latitude`, `country`, `date`) 
        VALUES ('$phone','$lon','$lat','$con','$datetime')";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: Well, you need to escape your inputs. Use prepared statements with PDO, and ditch mysqli* functions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you're initiating the SQL query but I would use a `form`:

```
<form>
    <input name="con" id="con" value="">
    <input name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
    document.getElementById('con').value = data.address.country;
</script>

<?php
$con = $_POST['$con'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `searched1`
                (`search`, `longitude`, `latitude`, `country`, `date`) 
        VALUES ('$phone','$lon','$lat','$con','$datetime')";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to the previous answer that Edward wrote, whats wrong with this is that you can never get a value from Javascript into a PHP variable like this.

That code is rendered on the server, and Js only renders in the 'viewers' browser.

At best this would just input a string containing your script function. You should use a form or Ajax to send data to the PHP script/function which executes the database insert query. That's the proper way.